How can I convert effect estimates to be on the same scale?
I am doing a meta-analysis of studies that examine the effect of air pollution (continuous exposure) on a health outcome. Many of the studies report effect estimates for different units of exposure. For example, some studies report an effect estimate per ug/m^3 increase and others report an effect estimate per 10 ug/m^3 increase. What is the proper way to convert the effect estimates (including odds ratios, risk ratios, and hazard ratios), as well as their confidence intervals/standard errors, so that they can be interpreted by the same unit increase? Thank you in advance for any help!

The question is not clear. Do you have common estimators calculated on different scales for their predictors? That is a simple multiplication problem. Or do you have disparate study results reported as ORs, RRs, and HRs, that you want to compare like in a forest plot?

More the former. I do have study results that report different effect estimates (ORs, RRs, and HRs), but I am meta-analyzing them separately. I just want to be able to have my effect estimates all on the same scale and how to properly do that.

If an OR (say 1.05) compared risk of death for groups differing by 1 year in age, the OR corresponding to a 5 year difference would be calculated as (1.05 ^ 5) = 1.28. The same is true of HR and RR. Does that answer your question?

Since it seems there is some potential change of the effect here based off the measurement, one could possibly include measurement method as a random effect in the meta-analysis while leaving the bivariate association fixed. Though that may be a more indirect way of dealing with the problem.

I think I see the thrust of this question but I don't yet see why it isn't answered simply by "the effect in a linear model per 10 ug/m^3 is ten times the effect per 1 ug/m^3."  Evidently you have a more complicated situation in mind, but what would it be?
